# Weird Error in scrapy (CENTOS 6.2)

Tags: python, centos, scrapy

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.14.4-py2.7.egg/scrapy/selector  /__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from scrapy.selector.lxmlsel import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.14.4-py2.7.egg/scrapy/selector /lxmlsel.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.utils.misc import extract_regex
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.14.4-py2.7.egg/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 7, in <module>
    from w3lib.html import remove_entities
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/w3lib-1.2-py2.7.egg/w3lib/html.py", line 10, in <module>
    from w3lib.url import safe_url_string
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/w3lib-1.2-py2.7.egg/w3lib/url.py", line 11, in <module>
    import cgi
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/cgi.py", line 51, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 45, in <module>
    from math import log as _log, exp as _exp, pi as _pi, e as _e, ceil as _ceil
  File "math.py", line 3, in <module>
   from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
ImportError: cannot import name HtmlXPathSelector
```

I am using python2.7, I used to work on ubuntu and I never faced this kind of problem, but in CentOS I am getting this error, by the way I installed scrapy thats why you can see the first command working perfectly.

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
```

One more thing, what "from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector"  has to do with math.py which is in the same folder

Comment: After you do `import scrapy` what are your results from `dir(scrapy.selector)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... This is not a problem with you, rather with CentOS vs. Ubuntu.

How did you install it? using `pip` or `yum`?

If you installed it from `yum` most likely the package is broken... 
(just out of curiosity, it would be good to know where you downloaded the package from).

Comment: Thanks OZ123,f for your quicky reply, I installed so-many versions of python because of my stupidity, now i am manually deleting everything and restoring the python, inform you once it is working